# Wipe an encrypted system truecrypt disc and reinstall Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, truecrypt

I am trying to reinstall an OS on my truecrypt device. The whole drive was encrypted and now I want to delete EVERYTHING without decrypting the stuff.

I have tried different approaches like GParted and similar, but without any success:

- GParted: I deleted both partitions and created a new one (ntfs formatted)
- Used the rescue tools of Windows 7 setup (fixmbr), but same problem.

The setup says it needs a driver (Using browse shows up my formatted device). Googling shows up that it should be a problem with TrueCrypt.
I never had problems before. They appeared after using TC to encrypt the system drive.

Is there no way to wipe the whole drive to allow a reinstall?

Thanks for any hints.

Comment: "I have tried different approaches like GParted and similar, but without any success." Edit your question and tell us what went wrong, and what you expected to happen, when you attempted to use GParted or similar and we may be able to help you.

Comment: If the entire drive was encrypted just getting rid of the parition would wipe the contents.

Comment: Okay, added some more information. :)

Comment: @CSchulz - Just delete all partitions.  Use the Windows installer to create a new partition.

Comment: Doesn't work. The setup has never accepted the drive as possible target. There is no difference between the manual erase of partition or not. You can see the drive as browsable device to find drivers but not more.  
Do I have to delete something else? Mark the device other or similar?

Comment: have you tried applying a new partition table in Gparted? removing your partitions won't kill the partition table, and it may be of an incompatible type for windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was caused by something else. To delete the encrypted system disc, you can use the suggested solutions with gparted, diskpart or dd.

The solution for my problem was [switching the USB port](https://superuser.com/a/402438/75227). But it is not the full truth, it seems to be a problem with USB 3.0, mentioned [here](https://superuser.com/a/402439/75227). So it was a problem with the windows installer, not TrueCrypt itself.

Comment: In its initial version, it wasn't apparent you were actually answering your own question ("use one of the suggested solutions"). But now that's more evident, so thanks for editing it.

Answer (score 1):

boot your GParted CD and see if you can find a terminal window. Then make note of the drive you want to wipe is it sda sdb sdc sdd or what.

Then try: (Replace sda with whatever drive you want to wipe.)

> dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=512 count=20000

reboot and see if you can install windows now.

Answer (score 1):

On windows, if you can get windows to recognise it as a disk, do

```
diskpart
list disks
select <your disk>
clean disk <your disk number>
```

After which you should be good to go.