# Which usb drive the system boots from in case multiple bootable usb drives are plugged in?

Tags: windows-7, boot, usb, multi-boot, bootable-media

Just now while installing Windows 7 from a bootable USB which wasn't successfully because of some bizarre *Select driver to be installed.* issue, before the setup had even started, after which I thought of connecting my passport drive which has Ubuntu on it to check what was wrong, which too didn't boot because of [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/247541/gave-up-waiting-for-root-device-on-ubuntu-12-10). (No the Ubuntu wasn't corrupted I checked it elsewhere, worked fine).

**The *main* question:**

After connecting my passport drive it occurred to me, what if I hadn't taken out my Windows 7 bootable USB. Which one of the two bootable would have taken priority over the other? And why? After all in the BIOS we only specify USB as the first boot priority not the USB port priority.

**Bonus question:**

What on earth do you think is wrong with this machine I am trying install Windows 7 on? I have tried all the drivers at my disposal.

Comment: the driver issue can come from using a usb 3.0 port instead of 2.0

Comment: @LorenzoVonMatterhorn hats off. [Bonus question asked in somewhat detail](http://superuser.com/questions/648160/select-driver-to-be-installed-issue-while-installing-windows-7-from-usb).

Answer (score 2):

> Which one of the two bootable would have taken priority over the
>   other?

This entirely depends on the boot order configured in BIOS/UEFI.

Comment: USB is USB to many systems.  I've seen a fewer newer BIOS/UEFI implementations that on the boot menu let you select USB devices individually, e.g. might say "USB: Sandisk Cruzer" or something similar", allowing you to differentiate if you have multiple devices attached.

Answer (score 0):

When doing sensitive tasks, always do your best to have a clean environment suitable for your task.
In this case, if you dont need it, unplug it.

Leave only the desired installation media plugged-in.

note: make sure you use a usb 2.0 port and not 3.0 port.

note2: the problem with your passport probably relies on your fstab. recheck your UUID's mounted there and corresponding partitions.

As it seems unclear why i asked to take preference for an usb 2.0 port, [here](https://superuser.com/a/402439/179299) is the reason.

Comment: How does this answer either of the author's questions?

Comment: @Ramhound using usb 2.0 over 3.0 addresses the driver issue. plugging in only ONE usb addresses the fact his BIOS only allows "USB" to be selected as boot, not a specific usb media. the fstab issue addresses the failing to mount by UUID episode.

Comment: He already tried to use one device though and it didn't work.

Comment: I had done it in the same manner you pointed out. My question is what if someone did? Be it intentionally. And since computers are largely deterministic how would it determine which one to choose from? Your answer to the bonus question is very well deserved [here](http://superuser.com/questions/648160/select-driver-to-be-installed-issue-while-installing-windows-7-from-usb), as mentioned above.

Comment: i provided a link to another SU answer that answers the driver issue. also, keep in mind if you changed the fstab on another machine, it MAY expect other UUID not present on your current machine, thus causing the error you experienced.

Answer (score 0):

If the BIOS only offers one choice, it would probably be the first one it finds, which is probably going to be determined by which socket it is plugged into.

Comment: as stated on my answer: plug in only the desiered installation media.

Comment: @LorenzoVonMatterhorn, that utterly fails to answer the question by dismissing the situation that gave rise to it.

Comment: then how does your answer successfuly answer it?

Comment: @LorenzoVonMatterhorn, umm... by answering it.  Do you not understand the question?  It is which of the two devices will the system boot from.

Comment: and **HOW** does it perform the action of finding? does it have ID's? please use details and sources.

Comment: @LorenzoVonMatterhorn, the ports on a hub are scanned in order, hence why your choice of socket you plug the devices into determines which one boots.  There aren't any details because it is stone simple.

Comment: and in which order? what gives preference to start from one port over another? which port would be then? is it still "stone simple" ?

Comment: @LorenzoVonMatterhorn, omg.. whichever one is wired up to be "first", which is hardware specific.

Comment: and how do you know which is it? - that is what i want answered

Comment: if the QA does not know which is first and it is hardware dependant do you think he will open the case and check the wirings? isnt it "stone simple"-easier to just plug it alone?

Comment: @LorenzoVonMatterhorn, you have to try it and see which one was first.

Comment: read the comment above yours please.

Comment: @LorenzoVonMatterhorn, yes, it is easier... and irrelevant to the question, which asked which drive will boot if you *do* plug in both.  The answer is that it depends on which port it is plugged into.

Comment: if you read all his question, that is a side question - what he really wants is to boot the win7 installation. that "side question" as i named it, seems to me intentioned to prevent the external drive being recognised over the usb stick.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10681/discussion-between-lorenzo-von-matterhorn-and-psusi)