# "Select driver to be installed" issue while installing Windows 7 from USB

Tags: drivers, bootable-media

The start of this question is copied from [here](https://superuser.com/questions/648145/which-usb-system-boots-from-in-case-of-ultiple-bootable-usb-drives). And stems from the first comment underneath.

> Just now while installing Windows 7 from a bootable USB which wasn't
>   successfully because of some bizarre Select driver to be installed.
>   issue, before the setup had even started, after which I thought of
>   connecting my passport drive which has Ubuntu on it to check what was
>   wrong, which too didn't boot because of [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/247541/gave-up-waiting-for-root-device-on-ubuntu-12-10)(no the Ubuntu wasn't
>   corrupted I checked it elsewhere, worked fine).

**The *main* question**:

I have tried all the driver that were at my disposal, no use. Any solutions?

**Bonus question:**

What is the technical reason behind it? *Detailed would be much appreciated*

Comment: What tool did you use to make your bootable Windows 7 installation USB device?

Comment: read this. http://superuser.com/a/402439/179299

Comment: @Ramhound `bootsect.exe /nt60 e: /force` in elevated mode.

Comment: @LorenzoVonMatterhorn warrants a duplicate flag I guess than.

Comment: aamof, you experience the same problem as the other QA. i will not copy paste his answer here. so yes, i marked this Q as duplicate.