# ASUS USB drivers kill USB functionality on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, usb, drivers

I just built a new computer with an ASUS Z170-A motherboard and an i5 processor. I was able to install Windows 7 on it, dodging the [usual problems](https://superuser.com/questions/401532/why-does-windows-7-ask-for-additional-drivers-when-installing-from-a-usb-3-0-dri?rq=1) by way of a SATA DVD drive and a Win 7 installation DVD, but now I'm having USB troubles.  USB didn't work properly - the mouse scroll wheel doesn't respond, and the OS doesn't see any mass storage devices - so I went and got the [ASUS drivers](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/Z170-A/HelpDesk_Download/) for Win 7 64 bit. When I install these, there's no immediate effect (although Windows tells me it successfully installed USB drivers), but upon rebooting, nothing USB works, not even the mouse and keyboard.

I've had to run two system restores already trying to get around this. Is there any fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the drivers from the provided DVD, not from the internet. The motherboard manual provides instructions specifically for installing Windows 7, but I actually installed Windows 7 in a more traditional way (with an install DVD through a SATA ODD), and then launched Windows 7, put the Asus DVD into the drive, and installed the drivers from there. No modifications to the BIOS settings were necessary for me.

Answer (score 2):

The Z170 Intel chipset was a transitional design, one of the first to have only USB 3.0 xHCI controller, and lacks the more traditional EHCI host controller. Apparently there are some issues, so the most recent standard drivers for xHCI might have some compatibility problems. [ASUS recommends](https://www.asus.com/us/support/FAQ/1013649/) to try a special hack called "XHCI hand-off" in BIOS, to enable it.

Make sure you install the right driver for your hardware configuration. There could be a USB 3.0 controller by Asmedia, as the ASUS driver list suggests.

Also check with [USBTreeview utility](https://superuser.com/a/1181052/620011) what the actual USB configuration is, it might hint you where the problem is.