# How can I install Window 7 if if there is not a single driver to install?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, windows-7-restore

When installing Windows 7, the following dialog appears:

[image]

However, the list of available drivers is empty.

What can I do to populate this list with available drivers for my hardware?

Comment: [The possible duplicate of explains what you have to do exactly](https://superuser.com/questions/401532/why-does-windows-7-ask-for-additional-drivers-when-installing-from-a-usb-3-0-dri)

Answer (score 0):

I have done this before.

Get the model of your machine, go to the manufacturer's support site, download all the drivers for your machine.

Now have the drivers on hand as you begin to install (have them on a USB Key ready for access when needed).

Remember that Windows 7 is over a year out of support, so your success may be limited.

One thing to consider is that it may be better to put the Windows installer on a DVD / CD  and install from that.   Why? Better chance that it will find the device driver.  It may not be able to find your USB device.

All Windows versions from XP forward to Windows 10 have built in Ethernet drivers. Make sure the computer is plugged into working Ethernet when you install.

Comment: The more likely explanation is the author is trying to install Windows 7 from a USB 3 device.  Windows 7 cannot be installed from a USB 3 device without a driver.  Windows 7 once installed supports USB 3.0

Comment: That is a decent point and I added installing from a DVD / CD to my answer as that may have a higher probability of success.

Answer (score -2):

Back when I installed Windows 7 all the time I would use a PartedMagic disk to boot up the machine and download the drivers to a USB flash drive (PartedMagic is amazing at not needing any drivers).

**But if you have a Windows 7 computer with the key on a sticker... you can use it to license the same flavor of Windows 10.**

Get yourself a Windows 10 installer setup on a USB flash drive.

Just Google "windows 10 iso" from a buddy's computer with Windows 10, download the installer, and create the USB flash drive installer.

The installer will not have a problem with USB 3.0, unlike the Windows 7 installer.

- Pick the same version of Windows 10 as your Windows 7 key (Home or Pro)
- Do a custom install.
- Wipe all pre-existing partitions (assuming you don'’t need to recover anything, if you do grab it off first and then start over).
- Create a new partition (it will create a few) keep the primary selected and start the install
- Don't bother entering a key yet if it asks you during the install.

Once you are done and logged in go to:

> File explorer -> right-click "this pc" -> Properties -> change product key -> enter the windows 7 key

You will now have a fully activated Windows 10.